# How can I initialize a generic variable in scala

Tags: scala, generics

As we all know, we can initialize a object of template parameter `T` in C++.

```
template <typename T>
struct Cont{
    T t;
}
```

I want to do the same in scala, so I write the following codes. There are some other classes which extends `Evaluator`, and `EvaluateComponent` is something like a wrapper. I can write code like `new EvaluateComponent[BinaryClassificationEvaluator].evaluate(df)`

```
abstract class Evaluator extends Serializable{
  var predCol = "prediction"
  var trueCol = "label"
  def evaluate(dataset: DataFrame) : String
  def evaluateRDD(dataset: RDD[(Double, Double)]) : String
}

class EvaluateComponent[E <: Evaluator : ClassTag] {
  val evaluator = new E
}

class BinaryClassificationEvaluator extends Evaluator {
  ...
}
```

However it doesn't compile with error `class type required but E found`.
The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590821/initializing-generic-variables-in-scala) does not solve my question because I want evaluator to be initialized.

Comment: You either must receive the instance of `E` or a way to construct it. You can not magically create an instance of any arbitrary class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitation in Scala is the same as Java - generic type is erased at compile time, and no direct access to a class constructor like C++. But it can be done, through Java reflection:

```
abstract class Evaluator extends Serializable{}

class EvaluateComponent[E <: Evaluator : ClassTag] {
  val evaluator = implicitly[ClassTag[E]].runtimeClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[E]
}

class BinaryClassificationEvaluator extends Evaluator {}

new EvaluateComponent[BinaryClassificationEvaluator].evaluator // Returns a BinaryClassificationEvaluator
```

This being said doesn't mean it is a good approach. The takeaways are:

- The passed class in the generic parameter must have a default constructor. There will be runtime exception if it doesn't
- Reflection is slower than normal code

Different language program in different mentality. It is better to implement this using type class in Scala but it's another topic.

---

EDIT:

`Class.newInstance` is deprecated now. Use `Class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()` instead